# Regex: "Mod Rewrite" everything from a "wildcard" to an address, without changing the address?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I really didn't know how to write the title. I changed it several times before I posted. But feel free to change it to the most appropriate question.

I also can't believe I couldn't find an answer already to this pretty basic thing I wanna to. I searched both here and on Google but couldn't find anything that answered this.

So I have this default WordPress .htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But what I would like to add, is the possibility of having all paths beginning with `/cv/` to show the page for /cv/. So like a wildcard after, like `/cv/*`.

I tried with several versions of this:

```
RewriteRule /cv/.+ /cv/ - [L]
```

But none worked. Most things I tried redirected me to the "Couldn't find the page" page. But some just redirected back to /cv/. But I want the whatevers'-after-/cv/ should stay there. So if the address is for example `/cv/hello`, it should still be `/cv/hello` in the address but the page showing should be /cv/.

Don't think it should be so difficult. What have I missed?

Comment: i can't test it, but i guess that `RewriteRule /cv/.+ /cv/ [NC, QSA, R=301, L]` could do it. _QSA_ should keep your URL as is, _NC_ is not case-sensitiv, _R=301_ tells the mod to do a permanent redirect

Comment: ps.: since there still run lots of servers using apache 2.2, please add the version to your question next time. for the flags and some examples, see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: @meistermuh That gave me "Internal Server Error"

Comment: @meistermuh It's Apache version 2.4.39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it temporary (not a nice solution but..) by adding a rewrite rule in my functions file. So that everything from cv/* points to a specific page. In this case page with ID 8472.

```
/**
 * Add Rewrite Rule
 */
function custom_rewrite_basic()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^cv/(.+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=8472', 'top');
    remove_action('generate_after_header', 'generate_featured_page_header');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

So, this is just the solution for WordPress. But I don't know. Maybe the other answers on this page would have worked if it wasn't WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I set up a test now and got the following commands to work for domain.com/cv/hello
to redirect to domain.com/cv but keep the URL

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/cv\/(.+)$ [NC]
# make sure to exit here, if there already was a redirect (to prevent endless redirecting)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /cv/%1 [NC,P,R=301,L]
```

The "magic" is to *FollowSymlinks*, to use *P* that tells apache to proxy-pass the redirect, so that the URL remains the same, and to check if there already has been a redirect to the current URL in order to avoid endless redirecting

Comment: ps.: when playing around with .htaccess in general, hit *STRG F5* for reloading your URL to force the browser to really ask for the content any time and not taking cached ones, or close/re-open your browser. else, some modifications might not be commited from server to client, thus leaving you alone with the question "why is it not changing...?!" ;)

Comment: Yes, I even open up a new private browser window to test in. Sadly it didn't help. But I'm also wondering about where I should have your code. Can I just paste it after the `# END WordPress` row? Anyway that didn't work at least.

Comment: @PeterWesterlund try pasting it bevore `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d `. If this won't help either, I only can think of access rights on the folders: make sure that the web-process can access the folder

Comment: Which folder? I mean, /cv/ is not a real folder. It's a WordPress page with the title CV.

Comment: does the page for _/cv/_ itself show up? if not, then there's a problem of accessing that route that is not touched by the rewrite above since it conditioned on _\/cv\/.+_ which is not true for just _/cv/_   IF it does, however, I don't know why it's not working on your side. Placing the code below the rewrite rule for index.php should do it as it does on my side. I'm at my wit's end.